# Scaling of correlation functions

Tags: quantum-field-theory, renormalization, correlation-functions, scale-invariance

In book [Renormalization Group and Fixed Points](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783642363115) there is formula for **scaling of correlation function**:

[image]

[image]

But this formula contradict my understanding of scaling of correlation functions.

For free theory we have:

$$
\langle \phi(x) \phi(y) \rangle = \frac{1}{(x-y)^{d-2}}
$$

$$
\langle \phi(sx) \phi(sy) \rangle = s^{2-d }\frac{1}{(x-y)^{d-2}} = s^{2-d }\langle \phi(x) \phi(y) \rangle
$$

But from the book we must have **another scaling**:

$$
\langle \phi(sx) \phi(sy) \rangle =s^{d-2 }\langle \phi(x) \phi(y) \rangle
$$

There are two possibilities:

1. There's misprint in book. But the same scaling present in another lectures, for example see (5.23) [here](http://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/dbs26/AQFT/Wilsonchap.pdf).
2. The relation is more conceptual and I don't understand some valuable steps.

So my question:**how to obtain and understand the scaling?**

Comment: hint: what does the scalar field 2 point function look like if you include the wavefunction renormalization factor $Z$?

Comment: @Andrew, but this factor doesn't contain s!! Or explain your hint in more detail, please!

Comment: (Working in 4 dimensions with a scalar field) When you rescale $x \rightarrow s x$, the measure scales as $d^4 x \rightarrow s^4 d^4 x$. Then to keep the kinetic term canonically normalized, one needs to rescale $Z \rightarrow s^{-4} Z$.

Comment: @Andrew, Z is wave function renormalization?? But I can scale only field, and don't touch wave function renormalization factor.

Comment: The solution to the paradox is that $\Gamma^{(2)}$ is not the two-point function $\langle\phi(x)\phi(y)\rangle$.

Comment: @AbdelmalekAbdesselam, what is $\Gamma^(2)?

Comment: It is the inverse of the two-point function in the sense of matrix inversion.

Comment: @AbdelmalekAbdesselam, unfortunately no... I included picture with correlator definition.

Comment: You are right, but it's not fault... In most of the literature $\Gamma^{(n)}$ is the vertex function appearing in the quantum effective action, and obtained via 1PI diagrams. For some strange reason the author used that notation for correlations. The explanation then is 1), namely just a typo. In the present case the $Z$'s are 1 because there is no anomalous dimension for the free massless theory, but the exponent of $s$ has the wrong sign.

Comment: @AbdelmalekAbdesselam, thank you! So in presented lectures there's the same typo..